# Stylesheet parameter is blocking stylesheet changes

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

After making edits in my purchased theme's css file, changes would not appear after refreshing the page. After trying lots of tricks and things that didn't work, I noticed the following in my page's code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='app-css'  href='http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/css/app.css?ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Supposedly Wordpress is putting the "?ver=3.9.1" parameter behind the stylesheet url. When checking out the url with the parameter I could see the old stylesheet without my changes. When I removed the parameter I could see the correct stylesheet with my changes.

How can I have my site query the stylesheet url without that parameter? I'm also not sure why Wordpress is doing this.

Comment: since you are making changes directly in the theme anyway (and not in a child theme), you can go ahead and just add the version number of your choosing to the parameters in the wp_register_style or wp_enqueue_style function call that loads that script. Do a search for either of those functions inside your theme files (probably in functions.php) and look for the one that loads this stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

This article helped me out: http://www.agentwp.com/remove-ver-parameter-wordpress-css-js-files

Added the following to my functions.php file:

```
 function vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js( $src ) {
 if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' . get_bloginfo( 'version' ) ) ) 
 $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src ); 
 return $src; 
 } 
 add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 ); 
 add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );
```

Comment: This answers the question pretty well, but if you want to know more about version numbers added to scripts/stylesheets, look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a caching prob.

Are you using the W3TC plugin? If so, click in the admin topbar on Performance > Empty all caches, and refresh your page.

What you also could try, is open the stylesheet in your browser http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/css/app.css?ver=3.9.1, refresh this page, and open your site again.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has been answered very nicely here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/force-browser-newest-stylesheet/

A hard refresh / clearing caches helps but for your end users (who might not bother to do a hard refresh on their end), updating version numbers is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the way to go. In what file on my site can this version number be changed? I've check the theme's functions.php, as well as in /wp-includes/theme.php (but in the latter I'm not sure where exactly, how to).